# VBA: instantiate class A in a property of class B

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I am a beginner at excel VBA OOP and need help putting a class instance with a property into the property of another class. I have a way which makes sense to me but does not work. I'm not sure if its just a simply syntax/structure error, or if I'm missing the mark on this entirely.  Here is a simplified example which illustrates my problem:

1. Class A has a property with a string value.
2. Class B has a property that holds an instance of Class A, and this property takes a string parameter and passes it to Class A's property.

Class A

```
Private strProp As String

Public Property Let Prop(sProp As String)

    strProp = sProp

End Property
```

Class B

```
Private clsA As New ClassA

'''DIFFERENT ATTEMPTS OF THE SAME METHOD:

Public Property Let ClassA(strNameA As String)
    clsA.Prop = strNameA
End Property



'Public Property Set ClassA(strNameA As String)
'    clsA.Prop = strNameA
'End Property



'Public Property Set ClassA(strNameA As String)
'
'    Dim xClsA As ClassA
'    Set xClsA = New ClassA
'
'    xClsA.name = "Foobar"
'    clsA = xClsA
'
'End Property
'


Public Function message()
    msgbox(clsA.Prop)
End Function
```

Module (the classes in action)

```
dim xClassB as ClassB
set xClassB = new ClassB

xClassB.ClassA("Foobar")
xClassB.message   'should display Foobar
```

the error I get:

"I still get a compile error: definitions of property procedure for the same property are inconsistent or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParaArray, or an invalid set final parameter"

Comment: I am just really curious: are you just practicing aspects of OOP in VBA or do you have a real-life case where you find this design useful?

Answer (score 1):

Class A

```
Private strProp As String

Public Property Let Prop(sProp As String)
    strProp = sProp
End Property

Public Property Get Prop() As String
    Prop = strProp 
End Property
```

ClassB:

```
Private clsA As New ClassA

Public Property Set ClassA(strNameA As String)
    clsA.Prop = strNameA
End Property

Public Function message()
    msgbox(clsA.Prop)
End Function
```

...and add a `Get` for `Prop` in ClassA

Comment: I still get a compile error (edited in question above) with my version and your version. I also tried using Let and Set, still error

Comment: It would help to edit your question to add your current code.